# Trying to HTTP POST But Getting MalformedURLException: no protocol: yahoo.com

Tags: java, http-post

Overall I'm trying to write a script that captures the servers' response to an HTTP POST using java.

Unfortunately, I'm stuck at encoding the URL portion of it. While I followed several online example on encoding a URL, I still get `MalformedURLException...`

Any idea what might go wrong in the encoding process?

The error:

```
$ java client_post

Sending Http POST request
Exception in thread "Main Thread" java.net.MalformedURLException: no 
protocol: http%3A%2F%2Fyahoo.com
     at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:567)
     at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:465)
     at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:414)
     at client_post.sendPost(client_post.java:30)
     at client_post.main(client_post.java:23)
```

The code:

```
//package client_post;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;

public class client_post {

     private final String USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0";

     public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

             client_post http = new client_post();

             System.out.println("\nSending Http POST request");
             http.sendPost();

     }
     // HTTP POST request
     private void sendPost() throws Exception {

             //String url =<host:port/create/service>
             String url = "http://yahoo.com";
             String EncoderUrl = URLEncoder.encode(url, "UTF-8");
             URL obj = new URL(EncoderUrl);
             HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

             //add reuqest header
             con.setRequestMethod("POST");
             con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
             con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language","en-US,en;q=0.5");

             String urlParameters = "<string base64>";
// Send post request
             con.setDoOutput(true);
             DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
             wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
             wr.flush();
             wr.close();

             int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
             System.out.println("\nSending 'POST' request to URL : " + url);
             System.out.println("Post parameters : " + urlParameters);
             System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

             BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                     new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
             String inputLine;
             StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

             while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                     response.append(inputLine);
             }
             in.close();

             //print result
             System.out.println(response.toString());
            System.out.println(response.toString());

       }

}
```

Comment: Post the stack trace.

Comment: you should not encode port number

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are encoding url your url becomes like below

**http%3A%2F%2Fyahoo.com**

Dont encode untill you have something special in it.

Your programm is also throwing class cast exception

```
 HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
```

Above should be like below

```
 HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
```

Below is working programm.

```
package com.ds.portlet.library;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;


public class client_post {

     private final String USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0";

     public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

             client_post http = new client_post();

             System.out.println("\nSending Http POST request");
             http.sendPost();

     }
     // HTTP POST request
     private void sendPost() throws Exception {

             //String url =<host:port/create/service>
             String url = "http://yahoo.com";
//             String EncoderUrl = URLEncoder.encode(url, "UTF-8");
             URL obj = new URL(url);
             HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

             //add reuqest header
             con.setRequestMethod("POST");
             con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
             con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language","en-US,en;q=0.5");

             String urlParameters = "<string base64>";
// Send post request
             con.setDoOutput(true);
             DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
             wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
             wr.flush();
             wr.close();

             int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
             System.out.println("\nSending 'POST' request to URL : " + url);
             System.out.println("Post parameters : " + urlParameters);
             System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

             BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                     new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
             String inputLine;
             StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

             while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                     response.append(inputLine);
             }
             in.close();

             //print result
             System.out.println(response.toString());
            System.out.println(response.toString());

       }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're trying to encode *the entire URL*, including the `://` and similar characters. The purpose of URL encoding is to hide those characters in a path or query part, and they shouldn't be encoded in the main URL. Use `URLEncoder` only for parameters or `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` contents.

Comment: @Simply_me No, only characters in a query part or characters in the path part that aren't allowed in URLs.